# James–Stein estimator

Tags: machine-learning, estimation, least-squares, linear-regression

Consider a FIR model of the form $y= Ug_0+e$ with $e$ white noise with variance $\sigma^2$. We assume that we have collected N input-output measurements $y$ and $U$. 
The James–Stein estimator is defined as
$$\hat{g}_{JS}= \Big(1-\frac{(n-2)\sigma^2}{||U\hat{g}_{LS}||^2}\Big)\hat{g}_{LS}$$

where $\hat{g}_{LS}$ is the Least Square estimator. Knowing that $\hat{g}_{LS}= (U^TU)^{-1}U^Ty$, is it possible to write the JS estimator as in the form below?
    \begin{equation}
  \hat{g}_{JS}= (U^TU + \gamma_{JS}(K_{JS})^{-1})^{- 1}U^Ty
 \end{equation}
I am trying to compare the two estimators and I would like to have them written in comparable formulation. In principle, few analytical steps are necessary to rearrange the first formulation into the second. So, the kernel $K_{JS}$ and the regularization parameter $\gamma_{JS}$ are derived as
\begin{align}
 & \Big( 1 -\frac{(n-2)\sigma^2}{||U\hat{g}_{LS}||^2} \Big)\hat{g}_{LS}= (U^TU+\gamma_{JS}(K_{JS})^{-1})^{-1}U^Ty \\
 & \Big( 1 -\frac{(n-2)\sigma^2}{||U(U^TU)^{-1}U^Ty||^2} \Big)(U^TU)^{-1}= (U^TU+\gamma_{JS}(K_{JS})^{-1})^{-1}
 \end{align}
    If we can write (not sure about that) $||U(U^TU)^{-1}U^Ty||^2= ||y||^2$, where $||y||^2= ||Ug_0+e||^2= g_0^TU^TUg_0 + \sigma^2$, then
    \begin{align}
  & U^TU+\gamma_{JS}(K_{JS})^{-1} = \Big( 1 -\frac{(n-2)\sigma^2}{ g_0^TU^TUg_0 + \sigma^2} \Big)^{-1} (U^TU)\\
  & \gamma_{JS}(K_{JS})^{-1} = -U^TU + \Big( 1 -\frac{(n-2)\sigma^2}{ g_0^TU^TUg_0 + \sigma^2} \Big)^{-1} (U^TU)\\
  & \gamma_{JS}(K_{JS})^{-1} = \Big[  \Big( 1 -\frac{(n-2)\sigma^2}{ g_0^TU^TUg_0 + \sigma^2} \Big)^{-1} -1\Big](U^TU)^{-1} 
 \end{align}
Are there any ways to make this formulation look "nicer"?